# Change of measure in integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Following a derivation given in university course notes about measure theory, I found the following equality:
$$\int_\mathbb{R}x^2\,\mathrm{d}\mu=2\int_0^{+\infty}t\mu([-t,t]^c)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
How does one come up with this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}2\int_{0}^{\infty}t\mu\left(\left[-t,t\right]^{\complement}\right)dt & =2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int t1_{\left[-t,t\right]^{\complement}}\left(x\right)\mu\left(dx\right)dt\\
 & =2\int\int_{0}^{\infty}t1_{\left[-t,t\right]^{\complement}}\left(x\right)dt\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =2\int\int_{0}^{\infty}t1_{\left[0,\left|x\right|\right)}\left(t\right)dt\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =2\int\int_{0}^{\left|x\right|}tdt\mu\left(dx\right)\\
 & =\int x^{2}\mu\left(dx\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you went from $\mathbb{1}_{[-t,t]^c}$ to $\mathbb{1}_{[0,|x|]}$ ?

Comment: $x\in1_{[-t,t]^{\complement}}\iff t<|x|$. Small repair. Not $[0,|x|]$ but $[0,|x|)$.

Comment: It is clearer now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a measure space, $f\colon X\to [0,\infty]$ is measurable and $\varphi\colon [0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$ is monotonic, absolutely continuous on $[0,T]$ for every $T>0$, $\varphi(0) = 0$, and $\lim_{t\to +\infty} \varphi(t) = \varphi(\infty)$, then 
$$
\int_X \varphi\circ f \, d\mu = \int_0^\infty \varphi'(t) \mu\{f > t\}\, dt.
$$
(See Rudin, R&CA, Theorem 8.16.)

Your result follows choosing $f(x) = |x|$ and $\varphi(t) = t^2$.

Comment: Could you check your reference to Rudin? My copy's Theorem 8.16 doesn't seem relevant here.

Comment: On my copy (Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition) it is Theorem 8.16 p. 172, under the section "Distribution Functions".

Answer (score 0):

In the case when $\mu(A) = \int 1_A(t) \, \rho(t) \, dt$ for some function $\rho : \mathbb R \to [0, \infty]$ (i.e. $d\mu=\rho \, dt$) and $\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 \, d\mu < \infty$ we can use integrations by part.

Letting $u(t) = \mu((-\infty,t))$ we have $u'(t) = \rho(t)$ and
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mu([-t,t]^\complement) \, 2t \, dt
= \left[ \mu([-t,t]^\complement) \, t^2 \right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty \frac{d}{dt}\mu([-t,t]^\complement) \, t^2 \, dt \\
\end{align}$$

Now, $[ \mu([-t,t]^\complement) \, t^2 ]_0^\infty = 0$ since $\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 \, d\mu < \infty$, and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\mu([-t,t]^\complement) 
& = \frac{d}{dt} \mu((-\infty,-t) \cup (t,\infty)) \\
& = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \mu((-\infty,-t)) + \mu((t,\infty)) \right) \\ 
& = \frac{d}{dt}\left( u(-t) + u(\infty) - u(t) \right) \\
& = -u'(-t) - u'(t) \\
& = -\rho(-t) - \rho(t)
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \mu([-t,t]^\complement) \, 2t \, dt
& = \int_0^\infty \left( \rho(-t) + \rho(t) \right) t^2 \, dt \\
& = \int_0^\infty \rho(-t) \, t^2 \, dt + \int_0^\infty \rho(t) \, t^2 \, dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^0 \rho(t) \, t^2 \, dt + \int_0^\infty \rho(t) \, t^2 \, dt \\
& = \int_{\mathbb R} \rho(t) \, t^2 \, dt \\
& = \int_{\mathbb R} t^2 \, d\mu
\end{align}$$